# How do I rotate a rectangle shape from a specific point in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

```
translate(width/2,height/1.87)
  rotate(angle);
  angle++;
  rectMode(CENTER)//can i modify the rectmode and make it rotate at other point of the rect
rect(0,0,100,30)
```

Can I modify the rectMode and make it rotate at other point of the rect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rotate around a pivot point, you [`translate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate) move the rectangle so that the pivot point is at the origin of the coordinate system. After that, [`rotate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rotate) the rectangle and finally [`translate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate)it to its place in the world:

```js
translate(target_x, target_y);
rotate(angle);
translate(-pivot_x, -pivot_y);
```

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(300, 300);
}

// (-5, 15) measured form the center of the rectangle
let pivot_x = -5, pivot_y = 15;    

// Position at which the pivot point should be moved in the world
let target_x = 150, target_y = 100; 

let angle = 0;
let angle_change = 0.01;

function draw() {
    background(255);
    
    push()

    translate(target_x, target_y);
    rotate(angle);
    translate(-pivot_x, -pivot_y);

    noFill();
    stroke(0)
    rectMode(CENTER)
    rect(0,0,100,30);

    pop();
    
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    circle(target_x, target_y, 5)
    
    angle += angle_change;
    if (abs(angle) > 0.5)
        angle_change *= -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: interesting result but i want it to rotate at this point of pivot check out my current work what am trying to do https://editor.p5js.org/saidabdul80/sketches/0XH_Ghue3

Comment: yea i try changing it but wat i want is let it rotate not from the edge of the rectangle but relative to where there is pivot as in the link above

Comment: good now but not to the center let say 45% from the rectangle start

Comment: Sorry, the rectMode only take center and corner. but i want it to rotate from where there is a pivot. i am trying to make an static equilibrium of forces

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327785200/figure/fig4/AS:673103495573514@1537491787890/Free-body-diagram-to-derive-the-static-equilibrium-of-the-instrument-driver-and-of-the.png

Comment: @SaidAbdulsalam The code in may answer doe not rotate around the center it rotates around  `(pivot_x, pivot_y)`  relative to the center.

Comment: check the image link above, so it will swing relative to where pivot is

Comment: am currently new to p5.js and am using it to build lab system

Comment: please can you help me check this too  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65923743/how-do-i-make-shape-move-relatively-on-another-shape-p5-js?noredirect=1#comment116558263_65923743