# how do i make shape move relatively on another shape p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

i want to make square shape to be able to move on rectangle shape below it relative to it rotation.
please check my code here
https://editor.p5js.org/saidabdul80/sketches/-Adu8HzFZ

Comment: No. A link to an off site resource  is  not sufficient. You have to add the relevant code to the question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ok, let me update it

Comment: sorry am trying to add the code here it require all the classes, so it will be too much, but looking at the code you can help me check the object.js file and make it movable along the rectangle and adjust to the rotation of that rectangle, thank you

Answer (score 0):

@Said Abdulsalam I think the answer to your question is this.
you should move the one object with the same vareable as the the other.

eg:

```
 //rot for object 1
 int rotY =0;
 
 
 void draw (){
  // object 1
  rectMode(center);
  popmatrix();
  rotate(rotY);
  rect(X,Y,20,20);
  pushMatrix();
  // object moving relative to object 1
  rect(rotY,500,20,20);
  rotY++;
 }
```

this will rotate  rect 1 and move rect2.